# Restore Contact from Database PhoneGap/Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a small example Cordova/PhoneGap APP for Android. The Goal: Take a contact, save it to an external MySQL Database - Restore it from Database.

```
$scope.pickContact = function() {
        ContactsService.pickContact().then(
            function(contact) {
                $scope.data = contact.clone();
                // post to db ... code removed
            },
            function(failure) {
                console.log(failure);
            }
        );
    }
```

It works well, with one exception: I have no clue of to restore the contact photo from DB. If I save the contact, it is saved with the URL to cropped profile picture:

```
"content://com.android.contacts/contacts/18/photo"
```

This is also returned when fetching from DB, but when the contact was deleted - the photo is erased. Can I access the photo from Cordova and store/recreate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... seems to be an bug in Cordova Contacts Plugin. Regarding some documentation you can pass a base64 string like this:

theContact.photos[0] = new ContactField('base64', base64, true)

But the function in contacts plugin, to resolve this does not support this format.

platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/contacts/ContactAccessorSdk5.java

```
/**
   * Get an input stream based on file path or uri content://, http://, file://
   *
   * @param path
   * @return an input stream
 * @throws IOException
   */
private InputStream getPathFromUri(String path)
```

For a work a round: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/jTMu9Azjaa8